# constexpr variable initialization - clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, constexpr

Given the following code:

```
constexpr float twoPi = std::atan (1.) * 8.;
```

clang generates the following error (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f1bfe4501dc6025)*):

> error: constexpr variable 'twoPi' must be initialized by a constant expression

but gcc does not (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69ad282a93ef0ee6)*).

Which compiler is correct?